# Проблема с адресами изображений в css файле.

Tags: css

Структура сайта:
index.php (include"/tmp/tmp1/index.php";)
tmp/tmp1/index.php(//html разметка с парочкой 'echo')
tmp/tmp1/style.css(//например header{background:url(/imgs/fon1.gif);}) 
tmp/tmp1/imgs/fon1.gif

Ну так вот. Почему-то не отображаются изображения в главном index'e сайта. Точно помню, что раньше такие пути срабатывали.

Есть идеи, как можно исправить ситуацию?

---

Добавление.
Такое сложное расположение (tmp/tmp1/) из-за того, что возможны разные шаблоны (tmp1, tmp2,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите слеш перед imgs

```
header{background:url(imgs/fon1.gif);}
```

Ваша папка с изображениями находится в одной папке со стилями

Comment: Такой подход напротив может запутать при множестве папок, да и хранить css и изображения лучше в разных папках, со временем можно забыть где что находиться, так же со временем стилей и изображений может стать больше в разы, да и другому человеку будет проще в этом разбиратся, когда все разложено по своим папочкам (/images/, /css/, /js/)

Comment: Согласен, я собственно так и делаю. Просто человек дал описание структуры сайта
        
tmp/tmp1/style.css(//например header{background:url(/imgs/fon1.gif);}) 

tmp/tmp1/imgs/fon1.gif 

По этой структуре слэш не нужен

Answer (score 3):

Для справки:

мы имеем страницы **mysite.com/pages/page.html**
и **mysite.com/pages/about.html**

так же имеем картинку **mysite.com/images/image.png**

Путь к картинке относительно page.html будет **../images/image.png**

Путь к about.html относительно page.html будет **about.html**

но вдруг мы написали **mysite.com/index.html** и пишем там все эти ссылки, но указанные пути уже не будут работать, потому что относительно этой страницы эти файлы будут находится в другом месте, а если мы изначально поставим слеш **/** перед ссылко и укажем относительно корня сайта, то эти ссылки будут работать везде

**/images/image.png**, **/index.html**, **/pages/about.html**, **/pages/page.html**

Самый лучший способ избежать этого просто прописать путь относительно корня сайта и расположить их не в /tmp/tmp1/imgs/fon1.gif, а в /imgs/fon1.gif